# MySQL, foreign key constraint does not make any difference

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a database, with several tables. The "main" table, called `contacts`, stores information about contacts, each having an `id`, a name etc...

I also have like, 20 other tables, each representing a certain function, like `staff`, `media`  ...

Each of these function-tables, references the contact table, with a foreign key. I've recently added this constraint to all the tables, with the following query, here for the table `staff`:

`ALTER TABLE staff ADD contactsConstraint FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES contacts(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE`.

If I change a row in contacts, I also want the change to appear in the staff table - and the other way around. But the constraint does not seem to make a difference! 
The only thing it does, is to throw an error if I try to add a row to `staff`, where the `c_id` value is not present in the `contacts` table.

What have I done wrong? It should be noted, that I recently changed the database-engine to InnoDB, to be sure that my constraints would work.

I have also tried to remove the `ON DELETE CASCADE`, so only updates to a table would take effect in both tables, but also with no effect.

Comment: 'If I change a row in contacts, I also want the change to appear in the staff table' => this sounds like you are storing the same field info in contacts and staff. Normalize!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing different concepts in your question. When your database is properly normalized, a change to **data** in one table should never have consequences in another table.[*]

If you want to change the `primary key` and have the referencing records in another table `follow` the change, you have to use `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

`ON UPDATE DELETE` only deletes referenc**ing** records if you `DELETE` the referenc**ed** record. In your example, if you delete a record from `contacts`, all records in `staff` referencing the deleted record would be deleted too.

Please read the [MySQL reference manual about foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for more information.

[*] If you have the **same** field in multiple tables containing the same information, you have a denormalized schema, which may be good for performance, but requires you to make extra effort to (manually) update all copies of a field when updating it.

Comment: Ok, so the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` would only work when updating the primary key?
I guess I have to update the tables manually then. Thanks!